# Null field not inserting NULL from empty TEdit

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi

I add new order details to a table in my db.
One of the columns there is named `email`, in the form I created to add the new order in my delphi application and subsequently the db, I use `TEdit`s to pass the data along.

This is the code:

```
procedure TForm2.actAddComandaExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
if dbmodule.comenziConnection.Connected then
begin
    if addOrderForm.ShowModal=mrok then
begin
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.SQL.Clear;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.SQL.Add( 'insert into `r33758pi_tipotask`.`comenzi` ( stare, client, telefon, email, detalii, livrare, pret, user, status, observatii ) values ( :stare, :client, :telefon, :email, :detalii, :livrare, :pret, :user, :status, :observatii ) ' ) ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'stare' ).AsString := addOrderForm.ComboBoxEx1.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'client' ).AsString := addOrderForm.Edit2.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'telefon' ).AsString := addOrderForm.Edit3.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'email' ).AsString := addOrderForm.Edit4.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'detalii' ).AsString := addOrderForm.Edit5.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'livrare' ).AsString := addOrderForm.ComboBoxEx6.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'pret' ).AsString := addOrderForm.Edit7.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'user' ).AsString := addOrderForm.ComboBoxEx8.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'status' ).AsString := addOrderForm.ComboBoxEx9.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName( 'observatii' ).AsString := addOrderForm.Edit10.Text ;
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.ExecSQL ;
end;
end;
end;
```

If I leave `Edit4` empty on the form everything inserts but the field `email` for that order doesn't have a `Null` value, it shows just as being empty - not null but no data either.

The column `email` is set as `Null` by default in `db` so that's not the problem.

Screenie from workbench:
[image]

There should be 2 NULL showing up between the values there but it's just empty.

Any ideas why?

Using Rad Studio 10 Seattle and dbExpress components

---

**EDIT**

- **comenziQuery** is a `TSQLQuery`
- **dbmodule** is the name of a `data module` that holds the db components
- the **dataset** is a `TSimpleDataSet`
- the **comenziConnection** is the name of a `TSQLConnection`

For any future readers, please do read all the answers comments also, great stuff in there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An empty string is not the same thing as a `NULL` string. When it comes to SQL, you need to understand the difference.

You need to add some sort of logic to write string values vs null values, such as...

```
if addOrderForm.Edit5.Text <> '' then
  dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName('detalii').AsString := addOrderForm.Edit5.Text
else
  dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName('detalii').Value := NULL;
```

This way, if the edit control is empty, a `NULL` will get written to the table field instead of an empty string.

As suggested, this can further be wrapped inside a common function to save you on writing a ton of code:

```
function NullIfEmpty(const S: string): Variant;
begin
  if S <> '' then
    Result := S
  else
    Result := NULL;
end;
```

And then use it like...

```
dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName('detalii'):= 
  NullIfEmpty(addOrderForm.Edit5.Text);
```

Comment: Getting the following error: dbExpress driver does not support the TDBXTypes.UNKNOWN data type. Vendor error message: .

Comment: @tcsh Hard to say, because from your description, I was assuming ADO components. I'm also not too familiar with MySQL, as opposed to MSSQL. But the concept is the same.

Comment: Yup, seems to be a problem with dbExpress components, I'll look in to it, thanks! :)

Comment: Fixed by adding another param line and setting .DataType:=ftString and then replacing the .Clear with .Value:=Null; - worked just fine. Thank you :)

Comment: And if you now put this into `function NullIfEmpty(const s: string): Variant` you have reusable code.

Comment: There is no Clear method for parameter

Comment: @kobik That's what I figured, depending on the components. Someone else added that to my answer, but I just added the `:= NULL;` because OP mentioned exactly that. I know at least ADO has a `Clear` option.

Comment: ADO does not have Clear either

Comment: @kobik To add to the confusion, I was looking at `TField`... Actually you meant `TParameter`... Thanks, fixed. That's the last time I blindly accept Remy's edit :P

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is due to using `ParamByName( 'email' ).AsString`, which will set the email column to a blank string. If you want it to remain null I would use code like this to clear the parameter,

```
if Trim(addOrderForm.Edit4.Text) = '' then
  dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName('email').Clear
else
  dbmodule.comenziQuery.Params.ParamByName('email').AsString := Trim(addOrderForm.Edit4.Text);
```

Answer (score -6):

You should use TDB* components which handle automatically such problems.

Comment: Uh?  Standard db-aware components set fields to Null?

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: Hello Downvoter: This is what I do in my programs (ado, access). When you set datasource and datafield and leave the control empty, than the table contains a NULL in the datafield and you can after post check for NULL by e.g. VARISNULL()

Comment: OP has not hinted that they wish to use these controls. Personally, I don't blame them. They may make things easier, but they way they work is terrible and outdated. I only use the `TDBGrid`, and still I always perform my own drawing of cells.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Could you please give some more information about your comment, because these components are my work horses. Why are they outdated? What is the alternative? This type of problem is typically when you have to deal with NULL, but these components handle it very well

Comment: I fail to see how data aware components solve the OP problem. I agree they are way more powerful when you know how/when to use them but a TDBEdit wont save empty string as null *automatically* like you suggested...

Comment: @kobik You mix up different things TDB* do not deal with empty strings. When you enter nothing in e.g. a tdbedit it will save NULL in the datatable

Comment: @ChristineRoss, I do not mix anything. I know how `TDB*` components work. your answer is `you should use TDB* components which handle automatically such problems.`  which is simply not true. OP  explicitly wants to save empty strings as NULL. if you want to expand your answer based on your comments, please do so.

Comment: @kobik understand your point, but the problem to store an empty string comes up because he uses TEdit which results an empty string. When he would use instead tdbdedit he would get back a NULL value, what his database expects. So formaly my answer is not an answer to the problem, but an answer to the cause of the problem

Comment: @martynA I made a simple example which demonstrates what I mean. You get it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzAg0XZupfgTNTdrcVlfQmdYbWM). You have to set the connection string in the adoconnection

Comment: @ChristineRoss Indeed, but not everyone uses db-aware components for such things, most prefer or for various reasons use non db aware. Like me, for various reasons that I won't go in to as is not the point. No one is saying you aren't wright about the cause of the problem, but that was not the case here.